# Install tomcat on Google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, cloud

I am pretty new to this whole idea of cloud and started of with Google app engine. I was able to create the basic 'hello world' program.

When i tried to understand the difference between a cloud and a server I learned that Cloud is where you have an access to virtual instance created exclusively for you and you are free to choose and install software of your choice.

But I don't see such an option with Google-cloud/app-engine. What if I have a tom-cat based application server which I would like to deploy on a cloud? Will Google app engine be of any help or should I try other cloud service providers such as Amazon EC2, hp cloud etc?

/DJ

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The cloud type that you are referring to is called [Infrastructure as a Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing#Infrastructure_as_a_service_.28IaaS.29) cloud.

OTOH, Google App Engine is [Platform as a Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing#Platform_as_a_service_.28PaaS.29) cloud.

The difference is that IaaS are a bunch of virtual machines that you need to setup yourself (OS + app stack), while PaaS typically comes with it's own API, where you write your app against the API and the rest (sw stack + scalability) is taken care of.

AppEngine comes with it's own servlet container (Tomcat is also a servlet container), so from this standpoint you could use your code on AppEngine. But the problem lies elsewhere: AppEngine imposes a set of limitation on the apps:

1. app must use [GAE provided databases](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/storage).
2. app can not write to filesystem
3. app can not have listening sockets
4. requests must finish in 60 seconds (e.g. no Comet or WebSockets -> no push)

You might want to review the [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general).

Comment: +1 for the explanation, but I think a couple of things have changed now, for example: GCP App Engine now supports Websocket connections - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-websockets-and-session-affinity

Answer (score 13):

To add to Peter's excellent answer, note that Google also has an IaaS service called [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/products/compute-engine).

Answer (score 2):

Regarding other cloud query-
Before you start with cloud you might once try other options. Currently deploying application in almost all services are very easy.
few of them are-
Jelastic , Heroku , rackspace , nimbus , openshift etc.

Difference between cloud and server is very well explained already.

Since you mentioned about tomcat based application , I have worked with Jelastic for the same and found very easy to implement.

- http://jelastic.com/docs/tomcat
  http://jelastic.com/tomcat-hosting

Try all possible option , it will help you more .